# How can I draw XOR'ed line (or plot ) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, line, xor

I remember in pascal we had such a thing to draw line with XOR drawmode(or writemode in assembly)
e.g. to draw a line from (5,5) to (100,5) we would do this in Pascal:

```
MoveTo(5, 5);
Pen.Mode := pmXOR;

LineTo(100,5);
```

Do we have similar thing for matlab plot (or line) functions? e.g:

```
%  Pen.Mode = pmXOR;
plot(X,Y,'r+');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the property you are looking for is called `EraseMode`.  It is available on some graphics objects, but not all ... you'll have to experiment for you particular application.

Some examples:

---

```
figure
hPatch = patch([10 90 90 10],[1 1 8 8],'r');
set(hPatch,'eraseMode','xor');
hold on
plot([5 100],[5 5])
```

---

```
figure; hold on;
[x,y,z] = peaks;
hPeaks = surface(x,y,z);
hLine = line([-4 4],[4 -4],[10 -10])
set(hLine,'EraseMode','xor')
view(3)
```

---

Use `get(hLine)`, `get(hPeaks)` etc. to see what properties are available for a given graphics object.

To see all object which support the `EraseMode` property, type

```
docsearch EraseMode
```